# Optimal index in Postgres for append-only transaction log table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres that stores chat room presence events (join/leave) events.  The events are only ever inserted (never updated or deleted).

```
presence_event
-- id (bigint)
-- user_id (bigint, FK -> "user"."id")
-- channel_id (bigint, FK -> "channel"."id")
-- created_at (timestamptz)
-- event (char "join" or "leave")
```

Over a long period of time this table contains several billion rows, but the only online query I will be doing is counting join and leave events grouped by (user_id, channel_id) within a recent sliding window (now - 1 hour).

Is there a way that I can have postgres maintain an index only on rows created within a specific time (now - 1 hour)?  Otherwise I fear the index will be become enormous with nearly all the rows being irrelevant.

Comment: I think technically this is what https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html do. But I have no experience what the pitfalls could be in your use case :/

Comment: Use table partitioning to create smaller tables and because of that smaller indexes as well. Partitioning based on the date should give you the best results

Comment: or you can create a materialized view with an associated index which will query the table selecting only the most recent events and which will be refreshed periodically by a job.